# css3 3d transformation card flip, padding/margin/border will cause the rotation origin to mess up, how to get around this?

Tags: css, 3d, padding, margin, css-transforms

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/yWKMD/

Look at the example, when you click the element, it rotates around from the `front` to the `back`, the problem is that it's not rotating around it's center, it's like it's off balance, hold your mouse at the left border of the `front` side, click the element, and see how the `back` side's position is now off. They should be positioned in exactly the same spot.

I noticed that when I removed the padding/margin/border, it would rotate fine, but I need to have the padding and border on there. Is there a way to do this with padding and a border - so that it will rotate around the center, not off to the side?

Comment: is your back also positioned like your front ?

Comment: Yes, check out the jsfiddle. `#card div` is styling for both the front and back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner divs (#card div) are too wide (235 + 50 + 2) and/or #card too narrow (245). You must add padding and border to total width, or alternatively use [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) (with vendor prefixes).

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this by using a negative margin on the "flipped" div.

```
#card .back {
  background: #DDD;
  margin-left: -40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
     -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
      -ms-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
       -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
          transform: rotateY( 180deg );
        -webkit-transform-origin: center;
            transform-origin: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gmsitter/jm80wv7b/